# How do I install an extension of Kafka for PHP?

Tags: php, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is the extension that I am trying to install: https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka

The messages passed to the queue should be in JSON format.

Currently, I am getting installation errors:
1. The instructions ask me to install [librdkafka](https://arnaud-lb.github.io/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.html).
2. The installation link for the above step is [this](https://arnaud-lb.github.io/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.html). I am unable to install using the 1st and 4th method. This is the error:

```
checking for librdkafka/rdkafka.h" in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the rdkafka distribution
```

Answer (score 17):

**Quick Install Steps:**

**Step 1 Install PHP pecl and pear commands:**

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```

**Step 2 Install librdkafka**

```
sudo apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev
```

**Step 3 Install PECL-package**

```
sudo pecl install rdkafka
```

**Step4 Enable PHP-extension in PHP config. Add to php.ini**

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

extension=rdkafka.so
```

**Step 4 Restart apache server**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 6):

because you need another package [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka),you should install [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) first

- $ git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
- $ cd librdkafka
- $ ./configure
- $ make && make install

this way can resolve your problem

Answer (score 5):

For Linux Debian Stretch (9.13) actual flow is:

1. Install PHP `pecl` and `pear` commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install php-pear
   ```

   > **FYI**: Depends on your installed PHP version you may need to use concrete version package. For example: `php7.2-pear`.
2. Add backports repository. Current ext-rdkafka depends on `librdkafka` version 0.11.0 or greater. So follow [official instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/), but use `stretch-backports`.
3. Install `librdkafka-dev` package from backports:

   ```
   sudo apt -t stretch-backports install librdkafka-dev
   ```
4. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Install PECL-package:

   ```
   sudo pecl install rdkafka
   ```
6. Enable PHP-extension in PHP config. Add to `php.ini`:

   ```
   extension=rdkafka.so
   ```

   > **FYI**: You need to restart `php-fpm` service to apply new config params.